# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - The session is unavailable error

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run some Flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. For some reason I have the following exception:
    **RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.**

```
mod_wsgi (pid=28948): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restplus/api.py", line 583, in error_router
return original_handler(e)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restplus/api.py", line 583, in error_router
return original_handler(e)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
 raise value
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 260, in decorated_view
return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 167, in unauthorized
flash(self.login_message, category=self.login_message_category)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 410, in flash
session['_flashes'] = flashes
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 350, in __setitem__
self._get_current_object()[key] = value
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 101, in _fail
raise RuntimeError('The session is unavailable because no secret '
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

It's very strange because I created env variables and secret_key var exists. Also, I added the following code:

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config.from_object(ConfigHelper.set_config(sys.argv)) #<-- select config
app.secret_key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']
```

I even don't know if this code is called. I'm really puzzled. Have somebody encounter this problem? Thanks!

UPD. Looks like I figured it out. I added automatic redirection from http to https and it didn't work because I didn't set up https listener. The question why I saw this error message is still a puzzle...

Comment: How `set_config(sys.argv))` is supposed to work? How do you supply this argument?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski It just checked the arguments - if there is any "env" variable it takes its value, else it checks the environment variable called "env", if it still not found it takes "dev" by default. This part works perfect in other apps hosted on AWS but for some reason I have difficulties with this one.

Comment: Sounds like `ConfigHelper` is a custom class somewhere else in the code.  Could we see the contents of `/opt/python/current/app/application.py` to work out what's actually going on here.  I'm guessing this custom class might have something to do with [ConsenSys-Utils](https://consensys-utils.readthedocs.io/flask.html?highlight=set_config#consensys_utils.flask.BaseFlaskFactory.set_config)

Comment: Yes it it's a custom class but it has nothing to do with this problem. If it would I would see it in the stack trace but the app crashed somewhere much before this point.

Comment: `The session is unavailable because no secret key was set` : apparently the secret key was not set.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski it *was* set. The problem was different - see the update.

Comment: I have seen my share of magic and wonder with EB, so I am not entirely surprised...

Comment: @LukaszTracewski yeah there is a problem with their logs - they look outdated. For example I *really* had a problem with secret key, then I fixed it but logs still show the same error. Okay, if I wait some time, this error will shown higher but logs still can hide the real error haha.